# How to QDialog semi-transparent?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem, qdialog

I tried with QGraphicsOpacityEffect applied to the QDialog, but the result is a half gray widget and I cannot see the  background and the activity behind, top-level widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`setWindowOpacity`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowOpacity-prop) function.

> The valid range of opacity is from 1.0 (completely opaque) to 0.0
>   (completely transparent).